# Joomla 3 cannot disable custom plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla, internal-server-error

I just installed a custom plugin in Joomla 3 and now I cannot disable it.

When I click disable (or edit) I receive "Internal Server Error".

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.0" type="plugin" group="content">
    <name>Content - Availability Calendar</name>
    <author>Joomla! Project</author>
    <creationDate>2010</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
    <authorEmail>support@msc.gr</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.joomla.org</authorUrl>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <description></description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="calendar">calendar.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <params>
        <param name="unit_id" type="text" size="5" default="50" label="Villa ID" description="Villa ID"/>
    </params>
</extension>
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Joomla 3.x? When you say "custom", do you mean your own plugin or one from the Joomla Extensions Directory? If it's your own, can you please provide the XML code?

Comment: I mean my own plugin with the latest version of Joomla

Answer (score 1):

You're XML code is old and is based on the code used for Joomla 1.5. You need to replace the following:

```
<params>
    <param name="unit_id" type="text" size="5" default="50" label="Villa ID" description="Villa ID"/>
</params>
```

with this:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">

            <field name="unit_id" type="text" size="5" default="50" label="Villa ID" description="Villa ID"/>   

        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

Then for each new parameter you want to add, simply add a new `<field>`

Comment: thank you I will test it.
But the plugin is installed with no problem. Now I cant disable it.